# Interval with Youtube iframe api - clearinterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I am trying to sync the time only if the video is playing, and pause the sync then the vid is stopped. Everything works fine, but the clearinterval doesn't.

onStateChange is firing, so i'm kinda clueless now

Code:

```
function synctime(currtime) {
  console.log(currtime);
  //other logic here
}
var syncinterval;
var player;
player = new YT.Player("ytplayer", {
  height: "1000",
  width: "600",
  videoId: vidID,
  playerVars: {
    autoplay: true,
  },
  events: {
    onReady: () => {
      console.log("player ready");
      syncinterval = setInterval(() => {
        synctime(player.getCurrentTime());
      }, 500);
    },
    onStateChange: () => {
      let sStatus = player.getPlayerState();
      console.log(sStatus);
      if (sStatus == 1) {
        //playing video
        syncinterval = setInterval(() => {
          synctime(player.getCurrentTime());
        }, 500);
      }
      if (sStatus == 2) {
        //pasued video
        clearInterval(syncinterval);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: if you set the interval time to something longer (like 3000ms say) do you notice the current time getting logged twice every 3000ms? more than twice?

Comment: @MilesZew https://imgur.com/Z9S1QnZ probably yes, it does

Comment: @MilesZew I fixed it with putting clearInterval(syncinterval); before defining the interval again. It's wokring, but i'd probably need some more elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: hmm that makes sense, however I think you might run into further issues if you don't fix what was causing the problem - I think what's happening is `onStateChange` is firing more than just when you pause/play the video - if you run into other problems that seem related let me know and I can give you a decent solution